# Return detached objects or object id

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

Assuming that we have an EJB (EJB3) in the following context and the bean is called using its Remote Interface.

What is the best practice for returning database objects (in this case *user*),
which might be used in other methods?

```
public User getUser(String email) {
       ...
       return user;
}

public void removeUser(User user)
      //reattach object 
      ...
}
```

or shall I use:

```
public int getUser(String email) {
       ...
       return user.getId();
}

 public void removeUser(int user_id)
     //get user from DB
     ...
}
```

}

Comment: Who is calling this method? A remote client or another "local" bean? For the first scenario I'd go with a mapped pojo copy of User, in the second I'd just pass the entity itself.

Comment: this bean is called via the remote interface - so I have to create a separate User class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a separate common.jar and put all classes used by both the EJB server side and the EJB client side - such as User.class - into this jar. And use this common.jar both at server and client side.

Answer (score 0):

Combine the @Big Bad Baerni comment and @Szilágyi Donát answer and you got your problem solved :)